# How do I make it so when I press a button in JS, an image appears?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to learn programming, and I code things to practice and for fun. I tried to code it where when I click a button the button the text turns red. It worked but when I tried to make it add an image it didn't work.

Here's what I tried

```
<button onclick="TurnRed()">Redify</button>

    <script>
        function TurnRed() {
            let x = document.getElementById("Lorem");
            x.style.color = "red";
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = /HTML_Code/Ispum.webp;
            var src = document.getElementById("header");
            src.appendChild(img);
            <div id="header"></div>
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like following:

- Create a `img` element
- Add src attribute
- Append the img element to desired html element (here `#header` element)

**See the following code for an explanation (for example, here I have added a google logo):**

```js
function TurnRed() {
  let x = document.getElementById("Lorem");
  x.style.color = "red";
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
  var src = document.getElementById("header");
  src.appendChild(img);
}
```

```html
<button id="Lorem" onclick="TurnRed()">Redify</button>
<div id="header">
</div>
```

**Note:** Since you are using `webp` format, I would recommend checking browser compatibility here: https://caniuse.com/webp

*References:*

[`img`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) element

[`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) method

[`button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) element

Answer (score 0):

```
img.src = "/HTML_Code/Ispum.webp";
```

img.src  should be a string，and the string is a location of the image，in your question miss the quotation mark for the location,add it and have a try